# While using Angular post method, Response data received from the API is empty but the status is 200

Tags: angular

Using Angular's post method, I want to receive the response data (JSON) from a third API. When the request is sent to the API using Angular, I get the response status as 200 in the console. However, I receive no data as response, i.e.

```
Response {_body: "", status: 200, ok: true, statusText: "OK"}
```

and this is followed by

Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response

```
https://theLink/ThatI/wantToUse/customer/complaintlist with MIME type text/html. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.
```

I have contacted the API developer and he has updated the CORS configuration in his API. Therefore, I do not know why am I not receiving the response data.

This is the server.service.ts code:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Headers,Http} from "@angular/http";
@Injectable()
export class ServerService {
   constructor (private http: Http) {}
  storeServer(servers:any[]){
      const headers=new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
  return this.http.post('https://theLink/ThatI/wantToUse',servers, {headers: headers});
  }
}
```

here is the app.component.ts code:

```
export class AppComponent {
title = 'internship-app';
  servers=[
    {
      'token':'xyz',     //two keys, token and society, to send to api
      'society':'1'   
    }
  ];
constructor(private serverService: ServerService){}
onSave(){
    this.serverService.storeServer(this.servers)
    .subscribe(
    (response)=>console.log(response),
    (error)=>console.log(error)
    );
  }
}
```

If I send the keys and values that is Token xyz and society 1 in postman's   x-www-form-urlencoded method with the POST method I receive the data.
I am not sure if the servers[] section of the  app.component.ts is the correct way to send the keys and values to the API and if it's correct why am I not receiving any json data in console.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending `application/json` while it works for you as `x-www-form-urlencoded`.

You can use something like this in your service:

```
const params = new HttpParams()
      .set('servers', servers);

return this.http.post('/login', params.toString(),
        {
           headers: new HttpHeaders()
            .set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
        }
```